# Gutenberg post validation before saving

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to add a post save validation in the Gutenberg editor in the case post excerpt is empty. What I have now is:

```js
const { subscribe } = wp.data;

const unsubscribe = subscribe(() => {
    const editor = wp.data.select('core/editor');
    const notices = wp.data.select('core/notices');

    const isSavingPost = editor.isSavingPost();
    const isAutosavingPost = editor.isAutosavingPost();
    const didPostSaveRequestSucceed = editor.didPostSaveRequestSucceed();

    if (isSavingPost && !isAutosavingPost && didPostSaveRequestSucceed) {
        const postExcerpt = editor.getEditedPostAttribute('excerpt');

        if (postExcerpt.length !== 0) {
            editor.unlockPostSaving('excerpt-lock');
            notices.removeNotice('excerpt-lock');

            editor.savePost();
        }

        editor.lockPostSaving('excerpt-lock');
        notices.createNotice(
            'error',
            'Please add an excerpt',
            { id: 'excerpt-lock', isDismissible: false }
        );

        unsubscribe();
    }
});
```

But on posts save I get

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: editor.lockPostSaving is not a function

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I looked at tons of examples in the GB repo, in various tutorials but nothing worked.

Comment: may be try `wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').lockPostSaving` instead?

looking at https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-editor/

Comment: I tried with that, but I got `Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` the content inside the `if(isSavingPost...)` gets called 800 times and it then throws the above message